# Is it recommended to store changing data in JWT

Tags: oauth-2.0, jwt, spring-oauth2

As far as i know, the main use of JWT is that we can store the user related data in the JWT token itself and it saves unnecessary DB hits during token validation by the resource server. The problem is if i store the data in JWT that changes over time such as ROLE or User Menu list or User Status, how do it deal with the changes.

Consider this scenario.

1. An user with admin role has logged into the web application, at the time of login the user status is ACTIVE and the user's role is admin. The authserver generated JWT token with these information.
2. The access token validity is set to 15 mins and the refresh token validity is set to 8 hours.
3. on the other hand, an another user with "Superadmin" role either suspends the "Admin" user or changes the "Admin" user role to "Supervisor". Now since the "Admin" already has an access token or refresh token that is not expired, should i do an another DB check everytime when i verify the token or i should not store the user status and Role in the JWT token itself?

Answer (score 0):

It is not recommended to store such data in jwt. In your scenario its best if you attach only the user id with the jwt and check status of the user in each server hit. If you arite any logic to decode the token at the client, that would compromise the token's security.

Comment: Currently i'm attaching only the user id in the jwt token but i feel it defeats the purpose of it because JWT is supposed to hold large information unlike JSESSION ID which holds only the session ID

Comment: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7519 https://jwt.io/introduction/ refer these links for more info... and as of ur question... as the rfc says jwt is a means to transfer claims between parties... say a client and server. So according to the rfc you can have aything in the payload of the token, but as the use case demands handling of dynamic data, it is recommended to visit the server to be updated of the changes in the user object.